# Arduino WiFi shield working intermittently, "WiFi Shield not present"

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, wifi

I am trying to use the official arduino wifi shield, It works occasionally, but most of the time (when running the WiFi web server example code, or my derivitave program, it outputs `WiFi shield not present` on the terminal. I have tried updating the firmware several times, but it has not fixed the problem. Is the wifi shield always this unreliable? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a Uno rev3? See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno for differences between Revs-1/2/3

Comment: yes, I got an r3 Uno just for use with this project (although I also got it intermittently working with an r2 uno (using wires to compensate for missing pins, before the firmware update).

Comment: also, it seems to be getting worse, I haven't been able to get it to detect the shield at all for the last hour :(

Comment: Ok, what are you powering the setup from? The other main possibility I can think of is that the WiFi shield is drawing too much power for your USB port (some PCs can limit to 100mA). You could try a wall adapter.

Comment: I am using a USB port, but it was able to power a 60 LED strip with the arduino, It also does not work with a wall adapter. Could the LED strip (of which I intended only a few LEDs are lit (but all of which briefly lit accidentally) at a time have damaged the wifi module?

Comment: How did you wire the LED strip? If it was in series it would explain a lot, and the WiFi could possibly have received to much current.

Comment: I connected the led strip's Power to the arduino's Vin and Ground. It is the led strip here https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12021 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25503/discussion-between-forgemonkey-and-patrick-l).

Comment: It seems to not be letting me post in the chat :( (it say you must be logged in (which I obviously am))

Comment: It's because of your low reputation. Don't worry about it, a mod will probably clean this up later.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. The next thing I'd try is taking a multimeter to the pins and checking each one is making a good connection. Give the boards a gentle shake between tests to see if it's intermittent.

Comment: ok, I will try that. so you don't think that connecting the LEDs to Vin for power would harm it?

Comment: the multimeter shows that the pins are connected, shaking the boards did not help.

Comment: Connecting the LEDs to Vin while powered from the USB is not good.  You are feeding power backwards through the 5V regulator.  You should be running the LEDs from the +5V pin of the Arduino.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I'll take a look at the software and library and see if anything jumps out, but I think you need someone with more experience of the shield.

Comment: @Majenko, thanks for the warning, I intended to be using the Vin while powering the arduino and leds from a 7V wall adapter, and meant to (but forgot) switch it to the +5V pin when using usb. Do you think that could have damaged the wifi shield? How much power can the 5V regulator output? Could I leave the LEDs on the 5V pin all the time?

Comment: @ForgeMonkey, thanks for your help anyway :) .

Comment: @PatrickL It won't have damaged the WiFi shield, no.  The 5V regulator has a limit of 800mA, though the lack of proper heatsinking limits it to around 500mA before it gets too hot.

Comment: @Majenko, The 800 (or 500 unheatsinked) mA limit of the regulator is why I used the Vin pin, my power source can provide 7V at 2 Amps, which is enough to power half of the LED strip at full brightness white, or more of it when not full brightness or white. Although I suppose I should use the 5V pin (and limit the number of lit LEDs) when connected to the USB port.

Comment: There is another limit, which is the diode that is inline with the barrel jack.  That typically has a 1A limit, as do the physical pin connectors of the headers.  To power more than that you should run your LEDs direct from the 7V supply external to the arduino.

Comment: @Majenko Ah, I guess I need to rethink more of the design of this project then. :(

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the shield is not shorting out on the metal USB socket on the Arduino board. I don't know if this is still an issue but I've seen many Arduino boards with black electric tape on the top of the USB socket to insulate it from shorting out the shield.